# Make sense in the various caching

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching

I have an asp.net-MVC application.

I want to add caching to my app.

I know there are many caching utilities,

I know they differ in the layer where they should be used.

Can someone make some sense in the various caching methods?

- CurrentContext.Cache
- MSEnterprise cache
- ViewData
- StateBag
- output cache - VarByParams
- PartialView

**update**
what caching should I use for Dal? Bll? UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caching methods depends what are you trying to achieve. I haven't used all of those caching methods but I will explain how we use caching in multiple layers.

Lets say we have at least three layered web app hosted on multiple servers and access through load-balancer or some proxy.

For static data, or data that doesn't have to be updated very often we use System.Runtime.Caching it provides, Dictionary and we store data on a single server. Lets say we have some settings in application that we need on each request like sites metadata. We want to save trips and load to the database by caching it.

For things like blog we use distributed caching like memcached, all servers share some of their memory for storing Dictionary values. But since there is only one instance of data in cache, any server can change or remove cached item and all servers will have updated data. Database queries are often expensive so you keep already processed data in cache but you know when data is changed or removed.

For simple ui elements we use Output cache. Its very often method of caching on simple applications with little behind logic. You cannot control it well or removed it if data has been changed. We use it on static elements like caching partial view of navigation. It also saves trips to the database but should the database value be changed you cannot recache it from your business logic layer.

We didn't have the need for any other method but caching is often very important. We prefer manually caching in lower levels, it takes more time to write and to use but provide much better control.

Edit:
When using caching I strongly suggest writing proxy class for cache, so in testing you can turn it off to find performance consuming code parts.

Comment: what caching should I use for Dal? Bll? UI?

Comment: Well like I said it's not always the question of layer but what are you caching. But if simplified DAL and BLL use caching that can be controlled well like Sys.Runtime.Cache. UI you can use OutputCaching since it caches the result so you don't render views every time. You can use absolute cache time so output cache can refresh now and then if your data is changed. It is often used on high traffic site since it requeres least processing to show UI.